# Is there a way to force update an imported component in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

Here in App.js I want to update the SideBar I have in the Drawer once I open it:

```
    import SideBar from './Screens/SideBar';

    const AppDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
  TabNav: {screen: TabNav},
  LoginScreen: {screen: LoginScreen},
  RegisterScreen: {screen: RegisterScreen},
},
{
    initialRouteName: "TabNav",
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#e91e63"
    },
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />
  },

);

const defaultGetStateForAction = AppDrawerNavigator.router.getStateForAction;

AppDrawerNavigator.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {

    if(state && action.type === 'Navigation/NAVIGATE' && action.routeName === 'DrawerOpen') {
        SideBar.forceUpdate(); <--- Does not work
    }


    return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
};
```

For some context, once I log in, the contents of SideBar.js does not update once the state has changed. But once I close out the app and reopen it, I can see the updated SideBar with the username, etc. I'm using AsyncStorage. So I was wondering if I could force it to update?

I heard that react-redux can fix this issue, but I have no idea how to incorporate that in my code.

Comment: intro to redux https://www.valentinog.com/blog/redux/